# How can I get the Default files .. Networks / Hosts / resolve / and whatever else I changed to try and get up my webserver?

Tags: networking, hosts, resolv.conf

Does anyone have the original.. Default Hosts File, Resolve File.. and networks file?

Please someone help me get these back to normal so I can put up a web-server.  I'm tired, just to set up a  web-server.

Answer (score 3):

Issueing `dpkg-reconfigure -a` on the shell will reconfigure most of your system. This will recover most of the config files as well.
Files about your network and your nameserver are not really generic, so you should rather use the ones fitting to your setup and not someone else's.

However, here is are a generalization of *my* config files..

/etc/resolv.conf

```
 # this nameserver is running by Google.
 # Change IP to your local router or ISP's dns server for improved privacy(disputed)
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# DHCP use
# comment out the following line to use static IP settings

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# static IP use. uncomment to use
#iface eth0 inet static
#    address 192.168.1.90
#    netmask 255.255.255.0
#    network 192.168.1.90
#    broadcast 192.168.1.255
#    gateway 192.168.1.1
```